# Running gpupdate in System Context stuck in memory

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I've run into an interesting problem with running PowerShell via scripts through ConfigMgr(SCCM) clients. One of the relatively newer features of SCCM Current Branch is the ability to run PowerShell script on the target node through SCCM agent in real time. This agent runs in `SYSTEM` context and I have written a number of utility scripts which can be run from the SCCM Admin console on a number of machines simultaneously.

The PS script I am developing at the moment is supposed to GPUpdate both computer and logged-on user GPOs. The computer portion of the policy works fine through the `SYSTEM` context; however, to gpupdate the user portion of the GPO, I use task scheduler code to run it as the logged-on user.

It works as expected but *the user GPUpdate process continues to stay in memory, which I was struggling to understand as to why*.

It then occurred to me that it could be because of the logoff prompt (to complete the client side GPO extension processing) which users otherwise see on the cmd console at the end of GPUpdate when they try to run it manually. At least that's my hypothesis at this stage but I don't know how to dig deeper.

Since my script is running inside this SCCM agent "sandbox" which in turn spins up another Powershell which runs the user context GPupdate, I do not know if there is a way the "No" answer could be supplied to the logoff prompt of the gpupdate?

Any ideas?

Below is the full PowerShell script which runs on the target machine in system context.

```
#
cmd /c gpupdate /target:computer /force | Out-Null

$ExplorerProcess = Get-WmiObject win32_process | Where-Object { $_.name -Match 'explorer'}

$LoggedOnUser = if($ExplorerProcess.getowner().user.count -gt 1){ $ExplorerProcess.getowner().user[0] }else{ $ExplorerProcess.getowner().user }

If($LoggedOnUser.trim() -eq "") { "Computer GPUpdate Successful. No active user session" Return }

$TaskName = "Run User GPUpdate - $((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss'))" $ShedService = New-Object -comobject 'Schedule.Service' $ShedService.Connect()

$Task = $ShedService.NewTask(0) $Task.RegistrationInfo.Description = 'Upser GPUpdate Description' $Task.Settings.Enabled = $true $Task.Settings.AllowDemandStart = $true $Task.Settings.DeleteExpiredTaskAfter = 'PT0S' $Task.Settings.StartWhenAvailable = $True

$trigger = $task.triggers.Create(1) $trigger.StartBoundary = [DateTime]::Now.AddSeconds(5).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") $trigger.EndBoundary = [DateTime]::Now.AddSeconds(30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") $trigger.Enabled = $true

$ScriptCode = """ cmd /c gpupdate.exe /target:user /force """ $PwshArgument = "-ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -command $ScriptCode"

$action = $Task.Actions.Create(0) $action.Path = 'Powershell.exe' $action.Arguments = $PwshArgument $taskFolder = $ShedService.GetFolder("\")

try{ $taskFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition($TaskName, $Task , 6, 'Users' , $null, 4) | Out-Null "Computer GPO and User $LoggedOnUser GPO update Successful" } Catch { "GPUpdate Failed - $($_.Exception.Message)" }

#
```

Comment: I'd run `gpupdate /force /wait:0` just like that and call it done!! Well in your case, just add the `/wait:0` parameter, etc.

Comment: So actually within PowerShell you should just be able to run `gpupdate /force /wait:0` just like that and not within the `cmd /c` and without piping to `Out-Null`

Comment: I have tried with and without cmd /c. Same result.

Comment: let me try the /wait:0 and get back. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I won't be able to test until tomorrow unfortunately. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: I think this will work  *** cmd /c echo n | gpupdate.exe /target:user /force /wait:0 *** Will test tomorrow and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suppress gpupdate prompt

Consider incorporating the `/wait:0` parameter and value in with the `gpupdate` command. This should suppress the prompt for confirmation allowing the GP to continue processing while allowing further script logic to continue without needing to "wait" on it to complete first.

I've used something such as `gpupdate /force /wait:0` in the past with good success but there should be no problem running `gpupdate /target:computer /force /wait:0` or `gpupdate /target:user /force /wait:0` specifying which policy portion gets pushed to the machine and/or user.

[gpupdate (Microsoft)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpupdate)

- > **/wait:**
  >
  > Sets the number of seconds to wait for policy processing to finish
  >   before returning to the command prompt. When the time limit is
  >   exceeded, the command prompt appears, but policy processing continues.
  >   The default value is 600 seconds. The value **`0`** means not to wait.
  >   The value **`-1`** means to wait indefinitely.
  >
  > In a script, by using this command with a time limit specified, you
  >   can run **gpupdate** and continue with commands that do not depend
  >   upon the completion of **gpupdate**. Alternatively, you can use this
  >   command with no time limit specified to let **gpupdate** finish
  >   running before other commands that depend on it are run.

[GPUPDATE (SS64)](https://ss64.com/nt/gpupdate.html)

- > **/Wait:**
  >
  > The number of seconds to wait for policy processing.
  >
  > - **`default`** = *600 (10 minutes)*
  > - **`0`**  = *do not wait*
  > - **`-1`** = *wait indefinitely*
  >
  > ---
  >
  > If the time limit is exceeded, the command prompt returns, but policy processing continues.

Comment: Thanks. I tested the script with /wait:0 (I have left the "echo n |"  part intact) and it does look like it runs gpupdate in user context and then exits. But for full confirmation I need to do one proper GPO change testing. I am sure it will be alright but just in case. Thanks for all your help and efforts and following it up. Have a nice day.

Comment: Another thing I noticed with /wait:0 is that gpupdate.exe disappears within seconds from launching. Is that expected? As soon as it disappears Explorer.exe seem to get busy. Is that what takes over the gpupdate operations?

Comment: @Steve - Yes, it sounds like that is gpupdate doing it's thing after you run the command. I'm not 100% sure how that works with SCCM with the way you are executing it but the `/wait:0` allows it to move on without waiting for gpupdate processing to complete. To verify what GP is doing I always look in event viewer via **Applications and Services Logs | Microsoft | Windows | Group Policy** and then click on the **Operational** option to see the logs. If you look thru these logs on the client, you will see and be able confirm all GP processing operations for the most part.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. The Group Policy event logs do corroborate the successful execution of GPUpdate for both the machine as well as the logged-on user. The only thing is, due to the immediate return of  the gpupdate (wait:0) the policy updates (as per the logs) are happening in intertwined fashion for both user and the system but it shouldn't be a concern as long as the end result is success which it is.

Comment: Have a nice day.